# Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute width="-Infinity" jsPlumb

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, svg, jquery-plugins, jsplumb

I have a function that creates a line displayed in a modal, between the two `divs`.

```
//A function that creates line instance.
function myid_create_line_instance(){ 

    jsPlumb_instance[0] = jsPlumb.getInstance();              
    var id1 = 'tpl_preview_line_1_pair_1';
    var id2 = 'tpl_preview_line_1_pair_2';  


    var endpointOptions = { 
        anchor:'BottomCenter',
        maxConnections:1,                      
        endpoint:['Rectangle',{width:'1px', height:'1px' }], 
        paintStyle:{fillStyle:'#00000', dashstyle:'3 3'},
        connectorStyle:{lineWidth:'1px',strokeStyle:'#000000'},
        connector:['Straight'],                                          
    };

    div1Endpoint = jsPlumb_instance[0].addEndpoint(id1, endpointOptions);
    div2Endpoint = jsPlumb_instance[0].addEndpoint(id2, endpointOptions);       

    jsPlumb_instance[0].connect({   
        source:div1Endpoint,
        target:div2Endpoint,
    }); 
    jsPlumb_instance[0].draggable(id1);
    jsPlumb_instance[0].draggable(id2);
}
```

After executing the code, it throws 2 error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute width="-Infinity" jsPlumb- 
2.1.2.js?o9evom:12902
_attr jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:12902
paint jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:13086
_ju.extend.paint jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:8626
(anonymous function) jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:2692
redraw jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:9322
_draw jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:3649
_currentInstance.finaliseConnection jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:3926
connect jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:4253
myid_create_line_instance myid_templates.js?o9evom:4614
myid_template_display_line myid_templates.js?o9evom:2215
jQuery.fn.myid_choose_template myid_templates.js?o9evom:4812
Drupal.ajax.commands.invoke ajax.js?v=7.34:608
Drupal.ajax.success ajax.js?v=7.34:400
ajax.options.success ajax.js?v=7.34:164
c jquery-1.10.2.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:3160
k jquery-1.10.2.js:8235
r jquery-1.10.2.js:8778
```

Second error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute height="-Infinity" jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:12902
_attr jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:12902
paint jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:13086
_ju.extend.paint jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:8626
(anonymous function) jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:2692
redraw jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:9322
_draw jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:3649
_currentInstance.finaliseConnection jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:3926
connect jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?o9evom:4253
myid_create_line_instance myid_templates.js?o9evom:4614
myid_template_display_line myid_templates.js?o9evom:2215
jQuery.fn.myid_choose_template myid_templates.js?o9evom:4812
Drupal.ajax.commands.invoke ajax.js?v=7.34:608
Drupal.ajax.success ajax.js?v=7.34:400
ajax.options.success ajax.js?v=7.34:164
c jquery-1.10.2.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:3160
k jquery-1.10.2.js:8235
r jquery-1.10.2.js:8778
```

I tried the first line of code below right after jsPlumb initialization; and then the second line of code below after connecting the two divs, with no luck.

```
 jsPlumb_instance[0].setSuspendDrawing(true);
 jsPlumb_instance[0].setSuspendDrawing(false, true);
```

I even tried the batch method, but nothing's change.

```
jsPlumb_instance[0].batch(function() {
//Codes about connecting the two points of line.
}, false);
```

One thing I noticed is the line that supposed to be connecting the two points in my modal was found not in the modal. See image below:

[image]

I also tried the code below, but the problem still occur.

```
jsPlumb_instance[id].repaintEverything();
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or plnkr that we can use as a working example? Have you reviewed Line 12902 of jsPlumb-2.1.2.js?

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same error when my container did not have any size. I can assume you should specify container explicitly for jsPlumb instance:

```
jsPlumb.getInstance({ Container:"editor" });
```